# Azure function service principal not available in AD

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've got one problem with the managed identity of an azure function.
So here are my steps:
1. Create Azure Function
2. At "Platform Features" I've created/enabled the "System assigned" identity. 
3. Now I want to create an secret key for this service principal, so I go to Active Directory -> App Registrations but there is no service principal.

I'm doing this because I want to do the following: https://wp.sjkp.dk/lets-encrypt-azure-functions-and-managed-service-identity/

Comment: If there is no service principal you need/can create one, right ?

Comment: The service principal is in the `Enterprise applications` not the `App Registrations`, select `Application Type` with `All applications` when you search, then you can find it.

Comment: Yes I can see it in the Enterprise Applications, but for the Let's Encrypt Extension I need to create an SecretKey of this Application and this is only available in "App Registrations" ?

Comment: Yes, it is only available in App Registrations.

Comment: Yes, but why isn't the service principal there?

Comment: `Enterprise applications` and `App Registrations` are different, if we enable the MSI, it just creates a service principal in your tenant, you will not be able to find the related AD App in your tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a secret for the service principal, you could use the powershell [`New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadserviceprincipalpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0).

**Note**: you need to make sure you have the permission to run the command, E.g. you are the global admin of your tenant.

```
New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential -ObjectId <service principal objectid>
```

[image]

The `application id` of the service principal is the `ClientId` which used in the link you provided, the `Value` in the screenshot is the secret.

**Update:**

If we enable the MSI, the function app has two environment variables defined. The `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET`, the `MSI_SECRET` is the secret of the service principal.

You could find it in the `Advanced tools (Kudu)` of your function -> `Environment`.

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity#using-the-rest-protocol

Comment: Ok thanks, but I get: Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.  I am global administrator for this tenant

Comment: Thanks, resolving the values from key vault is not the problem. I think the Let's Encrypt Extension need clientID and clientSecret to save certificate for the WebApp.

Comment: @bater Maybe you could [create a new AD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) for your function manually, then [create a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. I've created a new App and used this. Tahnks for your help!

Comment: @bater I missed the `MSI_SECRET`, you could also use it, see my update.